# How to bevel only one end of a cylinder?

Tags: modifiers, bevel

I'm trying to make a cylinder with one end beveled and the other end sharp edged, like a bullet shape. But whatever I do blender alway bevels both ends. I tried creating a vertex group with all the edges around one end, no dice, blender still bevels the other end.

Answer (score 13):

Using vertex groups should work. First select the top edges and add a vertex group, then click on "Assign". Then in the "Bevel" modifier set the "Limit Method" to "Vertex Group" and then select the vertex group you created.

[image: Vertex Group in Bevel Modifier]

Comment: Ok, Missed the final step, since I only had 1 vertex group I didn't realize I had to select it. To bad there was not some kind of error message saying "error - no group selected" when you tried to apply.

Answer (score 6):

1. Edit mode.
2. Edge.
3. Alt select (loop).
4. Ctrl B (bevel).
5. Left click.
6. F6 or bottom of tool panel.

.
[image]